# What is the correct way to calculate average using pyspark.sql functions?

Tags: pyspark, aggregate, average, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark dataframe, I have a timeseries of different events and I want to calculate the average count of events by month. What is the correct way to do that using the pyspark.sql functions?

I have a feeling that this requires *agg*, *avg*, *window* partitioning, but I couldn't make it work.

I have grouped the data by event and month and obtained something like this:

```
+------+-----+-----+
| event|month|count|
+------+-----+-----+
|event1|    1| 1023|
|event2|    1| 1009|
|event3|    1| 1002|
|event1|    2| 1012|
|event2|    2| 1023|
|event3|    2| 1017|
|event1|    3| 1033|
|event2|    3| 1011|
|event3|    3| 1004|
+------+-----+-----+
```

What I would like to have is this:

```
+------+-------------+
| event|avg_per_month|
+------+-------------+
|event1|    1022.6666|
|event2|    1014.3333|
|event3|    1007.6666|
+------+-------------+
```

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you to get desired result -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('event1',1,1023),
     ('event2',1,1009),
     ('event3',1,1002),
     ('event1',2,1012),
     ('event2',2,1023),
     ('event3',2,1017),
     ('event1',3,1033),
     ('event2',3,1011),
     ('event3',3,1004)
     ],["event", "month", "count"])
```

#### Example 1:

```
df.groupBy("event").\
    avg("count").alias("avg_per_month").\
    show()
```

#### Example 2:

```
df.groupBy("event").\
    agg({'count' : 'avg'}).alias("avg_per_month").\
    show()
```